# Bootstrap table sorting for date is not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsp

Here is my code with bootstrap table `table-responsive` where data populated by ajax. Here date sorted as string not date, please help me to sort date in `dd/MM/yyyy` format:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive" data-pagination="true" data-search="true" id="usageTable">
    <tr>
        <th data-field="servicealias" data-sortable="true"><spring:message code ="label.service" /></th>
        <th data-field="callStartDate" data-sortable="true"><spring:message code ="label.callstart" /></th>
        <th data-field="callEndDate" data-sortable="true"><spring:message code ="label.callend" /></th>
        <th data-field="sessiontime" data-sortable="true"><spring:message code ="label.sessiontime" /></th>
    </tr>                       
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have included the current version of jquery in the reference.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.4.0/bootstrap-table.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.4.0/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
```

Also you can use the below example for sorting using javascript

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e3nk137y/1434/)